# Uncalled private method in an interface

Tags: java, interface, private-methods, spotbugs

I have an `interface` with a `default` method and a `private` method, where the `private` method is called from the `default` method.

When running [Spotbugs](https://spotbugs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html), it issues an error that the `private` method is never called: [UPM_UNCALLED_PRIVATE_METHOD](https://spotbugs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/bugDescriptions.html#upm-private-method-is-never-called-upm-uncalled-private-method).

```
public interface Foo {

    default boolean foo(int value1, int value2) {
        return bar(value1 + value2);
    }

    private boolean bar(int value) {
        return value == 0;
    }

}
```

I'm doing something wrong or it's a [Spotbugs](https://spotbugs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) issue?

*Note 1:* When modifying the private method to `static`, it doesn't report the error.

*Note 2:* I've seen similar issues reported, but all are closed and related to `class` instead of `interface`.

---

**UPDATE**

A similar issue was recently reported on Github ([#1988](https://github.com/spotbugs/spotbugs/issues/1988)), but hasn't been solved yet.

Comment: this exact interface works for me

Comment: @ave4496 It works, but *Spotbugs* reports a bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spotbugs 4.5.3 reports this as "low priority" bug.

IMHO you have basically two options:

- report it to the Spotbugs project as issue (https://github.com/spotbugs/spotbugs/issues)
- tell Spotbugs to ignore the problem:

  - either annotate the method with `@SuppressFBWarnings("UPM")`
  - or use a filter file (https://spotbugs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/filter.html)

The solution with the annotation is probably easier to implement but clutters your source code.

The solution with the filter file might be harder to implement (if you do not use a filter file already) and the connection between the actual code and the filter might get lost, but your source code is not cluttered with annotations just to mute a noisy tool.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm already using a filter file that includes this case. Just wanted to be sure I'm not using `interface` private method in a way I'm not supposed to. Where did you find that '*Spotbugs 4.5.3 reports this as "low priority" bug*' ?

Comment: @Oboe i use spotbugs myself (it runs as part of the gradle build process) and its report contains bugs in three different colors: red for high priority bugs, orange for medium priority bugs and green for low priority bugs. These levels matches with the report option on the [CLI](https://spotbugs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/running.html): `-high`, `-medium` and `-low`. UPM is reported in a green color, indicating its a "low priority" bug.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. To make sure I understood your answer, do you think this is a spotbugs issue that I should report rather than a bug in my code?

Comment: @Oboe IMHO yes this is a bug in spotbugs. The default method `boolean foo(int value1, int value2)` calls the `boolean bar(int value)` method. Spotbugs cannot know if there is a implementation of the `Foo` interface somewhere that doesn't override the `foo()` method and therefore calls the `bar()` method.

Comment: You have a point that an implementation of the `Foo` interface can override the `foo()` method, in which case the `bar(int value)` method may never be called. But, that's also true if the `bar(int value)` method is `static`, however in that case spotbugs doesn't report any bug. Thanks for your help ;)